# Mono.Cecil - Add new Attribute type to assembly

Tags: c#, mono, code-injection, mono.cecil

I'm trying to add new Attribute type to assembly with Mono.Cecil.

I want it to look like:

```
internal class ConfusedByAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

But currently I'm getting the same result just without the `: Attribute` (System.Attribute) part.

Here is my code:

```
var assemblyDef = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(args[0]);
var tp = new TypeDefinition(
    "", 
    "ConfusedByAttribute",
    Mono.Cecil.TypeAttributes.NestedPrivate);
assemblyDef.MainModule.Types.Add(tp);
assemblyDef.Write(args[0] + "neW");
```

Any help is Appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: So what is the problem? Are you getting exceptions? Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Attribute as the base type:

`tp.BaseType = assemblyDef.MainModule.ImportReference(typeof(Attribute));`